How to break up cell array based on entry
I'm just starting out with Octave and I'm trying to write a for loop which would break up a cell array into new cell arrays and give each a unique, sequential identifier based on the entry values.
For example, if the first 10 entries are 0, I would want the loop to make a cell array 10 cells long with a title something like List_0.
This is what I've got so far:
startVariable = trackId{1}
new = []
for i = 1:length(trackId)
  if startVariable == trackId{i}
    new = [new, {trackId{i}}]
  elseif startVariable != trackId{i}
    break
  endif
endfor

I've started out with a for loop that chunks up the first part of my array, but I have no idea how to assign a unique identifier to each chunk or how to keep moving through the array based on a new value.

“Unique identifier” is reasonable, as long as you don’t mean “variable name that is named dynamically”. For a really long list of reasons not to do that: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/discussions/tips/849901-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval/2588421. But you can, for example, put these arrays into a cell array. Such that your “list_0” is list{1}, etc.

If the cell array you’re working with has only a single number in each cell, do yourself a favor and make that a numeric array instead. Cell arrays are meant for storing other arrays in (numeric arrays, character arrays, other cell arrays, or any combination of them). If all your cells are the same size and type, there is a good chance that there’s a more efficient way to store them.

I'm trying to understand what you mean by putting the arrays into a cell array. Perhaps I should expand on my problem too. I have a csv file with different attributes in columns. One column lists a set of particle IDs which I want to use to "chunk" up different attribute columns. I don't have a lot of coding experience, but I have some familiarity with c++. I was tasked to create a data analysis pipeline for a large set of csv files so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do that. I'm really unfamiliar with arrays and matrices.

I'm wondering if I might be better off with pandas for the csv part and octave for the actual data analysis?

I realize it's been a while, but providing a sample of the csv file you're trying to process would probably let us show you how to better parse, pull in, and store the data.  octave has a number of tools that work fairly well for parsing text data.
